# Summing based on condition

Tags: excel, comparison, row

I have four columns of data; Use Case (a text id), Site1 (an assessed value), Site2 (an assessed value), Quantity (number of runs). There are currently several hundred records and it continues to grow over time.  I need Excel to do a row by row comparison showing the total of the number of runs where Site1's value is less than the Site2's value.

I've tried using `Sumif` and other formulas, but can't figure out how to express the criteria correctly. For instance: `=SUMIF(B:B, "<" &C:C, D:D)`. Anything I've tried, if it has worked at all, simply does the comparison against the first value in the Site2 column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use a helper column. Add a new column with the value `IF(B1 < C1, -1, 1)` and drag it down. This column is -1 in rows where `Site1 < Site2`. Now you can sum the quantities of interest with `SUMIF(E:E, -1, D:D)`.

Comment: Thanks jspcal, that did the trick.  I was hoping for a more direct and "auto-adjusting" solution b/c in 6 months or so when I update, I fear I'll forget to update the hidden helper columns.  But all that being said, the spreadsheet is working great and I can move on to the next problem.  Thanks again.